# Dell Laptop does not turn back on after suspending

Tags: 20.04, suspend, dell

I have Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS installed in my Dell Latitude 3420, Intel i7 (11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1165G7 @ 2.80GHz), 16GB RAM.
Laptop does not turn on if it goes to sleep or if I close it. Same issue occurs if I do not use the laptop for long time , that is after it gets suspended.

Is there any way to rectify this. Please suggest

Comment: @ChanganAuto that should not be the issue with 20.04.3, which contains updated kernel versions to cope with newer hardware

Comment: Needless to say, perhaps, but you may need to hit the power button to resume it from the sleep state.

Comment: @vanadium Currently it runs 5.11 and Intel's 10th and 11th generations started to have good-not-yet-perfect support in 5.13 or newer. So, for this hardware, I tend to recommend 21.10 whenever possible.

Comment: @ChanganAuto you've never heard of the HWE kernels have you, which release updated kernel versions for newer hardware? The comment statement of "20.04 is not recommended for your hardware" is not able to be supported by any actual fact as far as I can tell...